# Sonarqube->SVN Authentication required error although supplied

Tags: jenkins, svn, sonarqube, sonarqube-scan, visualsvn-server

I'm setting up sonarqube scan jobs in Jenkins and I have ensured to provide my svn credentials in sonarqube at 'Administration>Configuration>SCM>Username+Password.

Most of the jobs scan fine with svn blame data however one particular job I'm still getting the authentication error as below during the scm data scanning phase:

```
19:42:06.883 INFO: SCM provider for this project is: svn
19:42:06.883 INFO: 10938 files to be analyzed
19:42:16.899 INFO: 3/10938 files analyzed
19:42:26.901 INFO: 4/10938 files analyzed
.......
19:46:27.024 INFO: 246/10938 files analyzed
19:46:37.028 INFO: 247/10938 files analyzed
19:46:47.036 INFO: 247/10938 files analyzed
19:46:57.044 INFO: 247/10938 files analyzed
19:47:07.044 INFO: 247/10938 files analyzed
19:47:17.044 INFO: 247/10938 files analyzed
19:47:27.044 INFO: 247/10938 files analyzed
19:47:37.044 INFO: 247/10938 files analyzed
19:47:40.763 INFO: 248/10938 files analyzed
19:47:40.888 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
19:47:40.888 INFO: EXECUTION FAILURE
19:47:40.888 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
19:47:40.888 INFO: Total time: 2:02:46.450s
19:47:41.075 INFO: Final Memory: 36M/3064M
19:47:41.075 INFO: ------------------------------------------------------------------------
19:47:41.075 ERROR: Error during SonarQube Scanner execution
19:47:41.075 ERROR: Error when executing blame for file foo/bar.java
19:47:41.075 ERROR: Caused by: svn: E170001: Authentication required for '<http://svn-app:1234> john'
19:47:41.075 ERROR: 
19:47:41.075 ERROR: Re-run SonarQube Scanner using the -X switch to enable full debug logging.
WARN: Unable to locate 'report-task.txt' in the workspace. Did the SonarScanner succedeed?
ERROR: SonarQube scanner exited with non-zero code: 1
Finished: FAILURE
```

What's weird is that I've ran this scan multiple times and this error always pop around the 240-250th file it was analyzing i.e. not always the same file. Weirdly, authentication went through initially, just that around the 240-250th file then this error pops.

Various solutions recommend to disable scm sensor (sonar.scm.disabled=true) which my requirements forbids. I need the scm blame data.

I have tried the following things:

- Restarting Jenkins Server
- Restarting Sonarqube Server
- Restarting SVN Server
- In jenkins job configuration> sonarqube analysis properties, setting sonar.scm.username and sonar.scm.password
- Deleting the job as well as workspace and recreating a new job.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out it was due to the `KeepAliveTimeout` parameter at SVN being set too low. When it was analyzing the particular large file then it hits this timeout (for instance, more than 1 minute on the 207th file as per my code example), causing SVN to rechallenge sonarqube for credentials.

Now other svn clients would've created a credential cache under `%HOMEPATH%/AppData/Roaming/Subversion/auth/svn.simple/` and retrieve this cache when this situation is encountered. However Sonarqube's svn plugin (svnkit) does not store credentials cache, and even if a cache exist it would not know how to read it(tried it with both encrypted and plaintext cache).

Editing the svn's `KeepAliveTimeout` parameter in httpd.conf solved this problem with a trade-off on svn server's performance theoretically - because svn would have wait longer before confirming a client is idle to close connection to reclaim resources, so increasing the `KeepAliveTimeout` parameter would cause svn to hold more requests at any given time.

References:

SVN Authentication Network Model: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/nightly/en/svn.serverconfig.netmodel.html#svn.serverconfig.netmodel.creds

Similar Issue: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/-Vz2zoOBS1Y

SVNkit Authentication Mechanism: https://wiki.svnkit.com/Authentication: 
https://github.com/jenkinsci/svnkit

Sonarqube SVNkit plugin repo: https://github.com/SonarSource/sonar-scm-svn

Jenkins SVNkit plugin repo: https://github.com/jenkinsci/svnkit